# CSS: Parent element's margin-top doesn't affect child's margin-top

Tags: html, css

Simple one that I can't wrap my head around. Look at the code below; in my understanding of the box model, the 60px margin on `#content` should push the entire `.main` div down, and the `.main` div's margin should start 60px down the page, but in practice the `.main` margin overlaps with the `#content` margin ([here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNNqqE))

```
<head>
   <style> 
    #content{
     margin-top:60px;
    }

    .main{
      margin-top:20px;
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Here's some content</h1>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Why is this happening?

Edit: And what are some proposed solutions? Note that adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent element is one solution but it isn't an appropriate fix; if I put an `h1` inside `.main` and try to put a top-margin on that, the same issue happens - and I don't want to be applying `overflow:hidden` to everything!

Comment: Maybe problem is related to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing ?

Comment: @nevermind Yeah man that looks like it. Is the only solution to code it differently and apply the entire margin to the child? For me, the way I develop webapps is to kinda build them + the design from the ground up, so at present I don't have content separating the parent + child elements but I eventually will. Would just be nice if the two margins didn't collapse together...

Comment: I think that good 'fix' would be to use padding, instead of margin? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjjMzp

Answer (score 1):

It's because of collapsing margins which you can read about [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Comment: +1 cause your answer like what it is, it should be a comment. but you don't have enough reputation right now. If you would add more explanation and not just a link (which could be death at some stage) also a solution for the problem ..  it would be a much better answer ..

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have not specified height of your content div. So when you give in something like .main in your #content div then the content div takes up the height of .main div because that is what the content requires.

So to make it a bit clear, if your .main div is taking up a height of 50px then #content will also be just 50px in height because you have not specified otherwise. So the margin-top of .main div is collapsing with .margin-top of #content.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of the box model as per w3c ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins))

Now to overcome this you need to float the elements as below

```
#content {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.main{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```